# Softphone on C# don't work incomming call

Tags: c#, winforms

Here i have how i accept the call but when someon is calling to me it is rejecting here is what i have tried but still don't works outgoing calls are working but incoming not can you help me? there is 1 point that it is alawys showing me call state busy

```
static void call_CallStateChanged(object sender, CallStateChangedArgs e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Call state: {0}.", e.State);

         if (e.State == CallState.Answered)
            SetupDevices();
     }


static void RegisterAccount(SIPAccount account)
      {
          try
          {
              phoneLine = softphone.CreatePhoneLine(account);
              phoneLine.RegistrationStateChanged += line_RegStateChanged;
              softphone.IncomingCall += softphone_IncomingCall;
              softphone.RegisterPhoneLine(phoneLine);


          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Error during SIP registration: " + ex);
          }
```

What I have tried:

```
static void softphone_IncomingCall(object sender, VoIPEventArgs e)
{
call = e.Item;
call.CallStateChanged += call_CallStateChanged;
call.Answer();
}
```

Comment: What soft phone library are you using? Unless it's part of the core .Net Framework it'd be a good idea to let people know rather than having them guess. SO is for programmers, not psychics.

Comment: Did you solve this issue, kindly help if you did?